# .htaccess output url depending on subdomain and file requested

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wish my .htaccess to have the following input / output patterns:

**Scenario #1:**

Input:  http://`subdomain`.domain.com

Output: http://www.domain.com/usersite/site.php?site=`subdomain`

**Scenario #2:**

Input:  http://`subdomain`.domain.com/tos.html

Output: http://www.domain.com/usersite/tos.php?site=`subdomain`

---

I managed to handle the scenario #1 with following .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/usersite/site.php?site=%1 [L]
```

but I do not know how to take care of the scenario #2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule so that it only handles `^$` (e.g. no URI, just `/`). Then duplicate the conditions and just to be sure you're not re-writing existing resources, check for **-f** and **-d**:

First rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/usersite/site.php?site=%1 [L]
```

Second rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.domain.com/usersite/$1.php?site=%1 [L]
```

That should handle your second scenario, redirecting `/tos.html` to `/usersite/tos.php?site=subdomain`